# sorting in the order of lowercase first then uppercase then digits and sorting the digits to with the odd no first

Tags: python, loops, sorting, nested, extend

The code I have written is given below. Can someone tell me what is the problem here, even though I am getting the required output?

```
p = list(input())
upper_case=[]
lower_case=[]
no=[]
for i in p:
    if i.isalpha() and i.isupper():
        upper_case.append(i)
    if i.isalpha() and i.islower():
        lower_case.append(i)
    if i.isdigit():
        no.append(i)
upper_case.sort()
lower_case.sort()
no.sort()
lower_case.extend(upper_case)
lower_case.extend(no)
output = "".join(lower_case)
print(output)
```

Input is `Sorting1234`. My output is `ginortS1234`. Expected output is `ginortS1324`.we have to sort the numbers too such that the odd come first can you help me simplify this code

Comment: Why is the expected output "ginortS1324" and not "ginortS1234"?

Comment: "what is the problem here even though i am getting the required output" - how is getting the required output a problem?

Comment: @ScottHunter the required output is very subtly different from the actual output.  I had to look a few times before I figured it out.  And like mkrieger1 I'm confused by the requirement.

Comment: @MarkRansom: But OP *explicity* says "I am getting the required output".

Comment: @ScottHunter yes, OP is very confused.  Moot point now, the question is deservedly closed.

Comment: there was also a test case to sort the numbers to such that the odd comes first i didnt notice it thanks anyways for the help

Comment: i forgot to mention it sorry for my mistake

Comment: can you guys help me to reopen the question i need to find a simpler way to do this type of questions i am new to coding and stack overflow sorry for the mistake from my side i did  checked the expected and my output but looked alike i thought it was a problem with the way i print

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming this is homework or something and you are supposed to do this a certain way or something? What are the specifications?

I shortened your code anyway if that helps in any way

```
p = "Sorting1234"
upper_case = sorted([i for i in p if i.isupper()])
lower_case = sorted([i for i in p if i.islower()])
no = sorted([i for i in p if i.isdigit()])

output = "".join(lower_case + upper_case + no)
print(output)
```

Or better yet so you don't have to sort more than once:

```
p = "Sorting1234"
p = sorted(p)

output = [i for i in p if i.islower()] + \
    [i for i in p if i.isupper()] + \
    [i for i in p if i.isdigit()]

print("".join(output))
```

Comment: it is just one of the text cases the input may varry

Comment: Oh so your answer worked for that case but not others? Does this one work?

Comment: the code suggested by you was correct for this one but fails on others. It is the Ginorts sort problem in hacker rank i forgot to mention a constraint of the problem we need to sort the numbers too so that the odd comes first i did it by checking it odd or even thanks for the help sir you helped me to simplify my code